# PHP : How to remove images in the directory of my website using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php

include "../../koneksi.php";

$module=$_GET['module'];
$act=$_GET['act'];
$Gfile_id=$_GET['file_id'];

if ($module=='galleryPhoto' AND $act=='delete'){
    $del=mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery_photo WHERE file_id='$Gfile_id'");
    header("location:../?v=gallery_foto&info=Success");
}

?>
```

I can delete the database row, but not my images in directory.  How can I delete the images from the directory?

Comment: Have you stored the image path or name in your database so you know what file to delete?

Comment: i have not stored the image path. my fault

Answer (score 1):

You can use unlink() function

[unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the file, of course it won't be deleted using those functions, you need to use `unlink()`:

```
unlink('path/to/the/file.png');
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

First, (and I hope) you need to have saved the filename of that file that you want to be deleted.

Then before deleting the row, you could get that filename first. Then just add/concatenate it in the path that the `unlink()` will be using:

```
<?php

// connection
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

if(isset($_GET['module'], $_GET['act'], $_GET['file_id'])) {
    $module = $_GET['module'];
    $act = $_GET['act'];
    $Gfile_id = $_GET['file_id'];

    if($module == 'galleryPhoto' && $act == 'delete') {

        // get the file path first that is saved
        $sql = 'SELECT file_path FROM gallery_photo WHERE file_id = ?';
        $select = $con->prepare($sql);
        $select->bind_param('s', $Gfile_id);
        $select->execute();
        $select->bind_result($file_path);
        $select->fetch(); // fetch single row

        // delete the file
        unlink('path/to/images/' . $file_path);

        // then delete that row
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM gallery_photo WHERE file_id = ?';
        $delete = $con->prepare($sql);
        $delete->bind_param('s', $Gfile_id);
        $delete->execute();


        header('Location: ../?v=gallery_foto&info=Success');
    }
}

?>
```